# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got '{'

Tags: python, cascade, emotion

i got this error in my old code
This the error when i run the code:
[image]

i cant seem to understand what's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the quote before the filename.

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/functions-min.js') }}">
```